# Swift generic child type always returns parent

Tags: swift, generics, pool

I'm trying to do a container pool of generics, however I find that when trying to recycle from a parent class, the generic inference can't be resolved properly and I just get the parent type instead of the concrete one

An example:

```
Enemy : Poolable {


   func die() {
       containerPool.recycle(self)
   }

}

Enemy2 : Enemy {

}


containerPool.obtain(Enemy2.self).die() //Crash with Could not cast value of type Pool<Enemy2> to Pool<Enemy>
```

//The container pool recycle method:

```
import Foundation

protocol Poolable {
    init()
    func onRecycled()
    func willBeObtained()
}

class Pool<T:Poolable> {
    
    var objects:[T] = []
    
    init(initialSpawn:Int = 0){
        for _ in 0...initialSpawn {
            objects.append(T.init())
        }
    }
    
    func obtain() -> T {
        if objects.count > 0 {
            let object = objects.removeFirst()
            object.willBeObtained()
            return object
        }
        let object = T.init()
        object.willBeObtained()
        return object
    }
    
    func recycle(_ object:T) {
        object.onRecycled()
        objects.append(object)
    }
    
}

class ContainerPool {
    
    var pools:[String:Any] = [:]
    
    func obtain<T:Poolable>() -> T {
        pool(for:T.self).obtain()
    }
    
    func obtain<T:Poolable>(_ type:T.Type) -> T{
        pool(for:type).obtain()
    }
    
    func recycle<T:Poolable>(_ object:T) {
        let concreteType = type(of: object)
        pool(for: concreteType).recycle(object)
    }
    
    func pool<T:Poolable>(for type:T.Type, initialSpawn:Int = 10) -> Pool<T> {
        let typeString = "\(type)"
        if let pool = pools[typeString] as? Pool<T> {
        //if let pool = pools[typeString] {
            return pool
        }
        let pool = Pool<T>(initialSpawn:initialSpawn)
        pools[typeString] = pool
        return pool
    }
        
    func preload<T:Poolable>(type:T.Type, size:Int = 20){
        let _ = pool(for: type, initialSpawn: size)
    }
    
}
```

typeStrings is always right, and the pool I get in let pool is the right one, but I can't cast it to Enemy2 as it thinks the T is Enemy...

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: `Pool<A>` and `Pool<B>` are not related even if `A` and `B` are related (aka these types are invariant); in Swift, generics types are invariant to each other

Comment: What do you mean by invariant?
I want that when calling recycle on parent, it actually recicles concrete type

Comment: The "covariance"/"invariance"/"contravariance" is just a terminology used, if you wanted to google it, but my comment was mostly about the error you mentioned as the cause for the crash. I can't comment on other things since your code example is incomplete (what is `Pool` and `containerPool`, etc...) so it's not immediately clear to me what's going

Comment: Hehe ok! Pool is just a array ob instances so when i need a new enemy i don’t have to allocate it, it is fetched from the pool, container pool is just a dictionary of poola where the key is the object type name. Problem comes when calling recycle from enemy parent class, type name is ok but generic T is enemy istead of enemy2

Comment: Best to update the question with more code details

Comment: just updated the question with full pool and container pool code

Comment: Maybe something is still missing, I copied the code and it works, no crash and the right classes are created/used